# CSS: Add background-image to :after pseudoelement with fade effect

Tags: html, css

```
#gallery div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#gallery div:hover::after {
    background-image: url("files/img/plus.jpg") !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 83px;
    right: 0;
    width: 83px;
    transition: background 1300ms ease-in 2s;
}
#gallery a:nth-child(1) div {
    background-image: url("files/img/bio/1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
}
```

I'm trying to add a fade effect to plus.jpg `background-image`, applied on the `::after` pseudoelement on `hover`. As you can see I tried with `transition: background 1300ms ease-in 2s` but nothing is happening..

[Here](http://luca-longobardi.com/bio.html) you can see the code live (is the gallery with 9 images.

Comment: You can't transition background images. Have you considered transitioning the `opacity` instead?

Answer (score 0):

background-images can't be transitioned. But since it's just a simple plus sign, I suggest the ff:

```
#gallery div::after {
background-color: #ddaa44;
color: white;
content: "+";
display: block;
font: 44px/44px verdana;
opacity: 0;
padding: 26px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}

#gallery div:hover::after {
opacity: 1;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```